# Can I build multiple classes into one .class file in Java?

Tags: java, eclipse, class, build, encapsulation

I am opening a .class file using COMSOL multi-physics, and it works fine for one .class file, but I can't open several .class files at a time. My problem is that I want to be able to build more complicated objects inside the class that I open but, when I import these classes and build the project, I end up with multiple .class files. When I open the main .class file in COMSOL, a "error running java class", which I assume is because I've only opened one class.

I am not very familiar with programming in Java, but I started trying to put my classes inside one file, but when I build there still 3 output .class files. Also, in case it matters, I am running on a windows 7 machine and using Eclipse... I would greatly appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Every new class has its own `.class` file, whether it's top level, nested, anonymous, etc.

Comment: Thank you @SotiriosDelimanolis. That is helpful to know. Do you have any suggestions as to how I can create more complex objects inside just one class?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that. Give us an example.

Comment: I suspect @Charlie needs a way to encapsulate the generated code for a whole project in one file. On that assumption, I've suggested generating a jar file.

Comment: I guess I want this class to "have" objects from another class. I guess that's like supporting encapsulation? I think I may look into adding external .jar files into COMSOL's default directory. Maybe it will have access to these classes then. I'm sorry if I'm being unclear, I'm not very familiar with java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a .class for each class. The usual solution is to combine them into a [.jar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_%28file_format%29). The .jar file can be downloaded and moved around as a single file, regardless of how many classes it represents. You can mark it to identify the main class, so it can be run much as a single class file.

Creating a .jar is one of the options in Eclipse for File-Export

Comment: Part of the issue may also be adding the code in question to COMSOL's classpath when opening the class the OP is writing.

Comment: Thank you @Patricia, I think this may be the most promising approach.

Comment: I think you may be right @chrylis, I'm going to look into this and exporting .jar files. Thank you everyone! This was extremely helpful!

Comment: I did a quick search for `COMSOL jar`, and found e.g. (http://www.comsol.com/community/forums/general/thread/33659/) which includes in one of the answers instructions for loading a jar as a plugin. It looks as though COMSOL is jar-aware, which I would expect for most non-trivial packages that can use a .class file.

Comment: That thread looks exactly what I was looking for. I followed the directions, but it doesn't seem to be working. I'm thinking maybe I have to import the comsol class files in every one of the class files that I made, or maybe I only need the auxiliary files and not the one that makes the simulation. I'm going to dig a bit deeper, but this looks great. Thank you again @PatriciaShanahan

Comment: @Charlie If you don't manage to work it out, and need more help, I suggest posting a new question about using a jar file from COMSOL.

Comment: The reason that I needed this to work in the first place was because my COMSOL GUI was not opening the class files. The resulting error said something like "Error running java class". I later found out that, it seems, the COMSOL GUI responds only one way to java runtime errors: with that message "Error running java class". I hope this helps others.

Answer (score 0):

No, You should create a new .class file for every class you want to have.

Answer (score 0):

If a source file has more than one class, each class is compiled into a separate class file.